# Need Suggestions for Unit Testing for Silverlight v4 with Prism v4

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am new in Silverlight, I need to implement Unit testing framework in my current developing application which is using technologies like Silverlight v4 with Prism v4.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of using a unit testing framework or going the TDD way is that the end result is loosely coupled application.

So it does not really matter what unit testing framework you use, all the unit testing frameworks available today are very powerful. Use the one that you and your team is comfortable with.

Here are some of the unit testing frameworks that work very well -

- [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/)
- [MbUnit](http://www.mbunit.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply.
As I am new in silverlight so I don't have much knowledge of Unit testing in Silverlight, As Silverlight toolkit also provides a testing framework and that I want to use in my project.
Can you please provide me sample implementation or any good artical link in which i can see how to write effective Unit test cases in Silverlight.

Thanks in Advance :)